# repository.save uses insert instead of update

Tags: typeorm

I am using TypeORM's repository pattern with a simple table, two columns, `estate_num` as primary key and `estateId` with mysql.

The `repository.save` [method is supposed](http://typeorm.io/#/repository-api) to insert if the record by primary key does not exist, otherwise, update it.

Instead, I get the following error:

```
query: SELECT `estate`.`estate_num` AS `estate_estate_num`, `estate`.`estateId` AS `estate_estateId` FROM `estate` `estate` WHERE (`estate`.`estate_num` = ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["0"]
query: START TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO `estate`(`estate_num`, `estateId`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["0","caae4e67796e4ac000743f009210fcb0467fdf87d0fbbf6107359cf53f5b544b79eefdfdd78f95d50301f20a9c3212cd3970af22b722e59313813e8c5d2732d0"]
query failed: INSERT INTO `estate`(`estate_num`, `estateId`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["0","caae4e67796e4ac000743f009210fcb0467fdf87d0fbbf6107359cf53f5b544b79eefdfdd78f95d50301f20a9c3212cd3970af22b722e59313813e8c5d2732d0"]
error: { Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I can run the `SELECT` manually, which is what I think determines whether to insert vs update. It returns a row as I would expect with the matching `estate_num`.

The entity model for this is:

```
@Entity()
export class Estate {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    name: 'estate_num',
  })
  estateNum: number;

  @Column({
    name: 'estateId',
  })
  estateId: string;
}
```

Note: the `estate_num` is *not* auto-increment, the key will be always supplied. It is odd, I understand.

Thanks!

Comment: you definitely do something wrong. try to test things on a minimal code, check the input before you give it to `save` method.

Comment: @Ryan Rampersad do you have a solution for this? I have the same problem. I tried the create() method and supplied it with the id it throws a duplicate error when even though I supplied an ID for it to update and not save. This giving me a head ache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your logs it's clear that you've passed ID as a string `-- PARAMETERS: ["0"]`, but `Estate` entity `estateNum` is of type `number`. Convert the ID to number before passing it to `repository.save`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was doing it wrong.

Before I was doing it multiple ways, but in the wrong way.

First I was doing it like this:

```
const user = User.create({ id: 1, username: "newName" })

user.save();
```

giving me an error of `ID Duplicate Entry`

---

Second I was doing it like this:

```
const user = User.create({ id: 1, username: "newName" })

User.save(user);
```

same error, Duplicate Entry.

---

Third I was doing it like this:

```
const user = User.findOneOrFaile(1);
const newUser = { ...user, ..req.body }
User.save(newUser);
```

same error.

---

And I just got helped and It should be done like this. You need to get the instance and merged it using `Object.assign()`

```
try {
      const user: User = await User.findOneOrFail(id);
      Object.assign(user, { ...req.body }); <---- SO ITS LIKE THIS
      await user.save();
      res.json({
        meta: {},
        payload: {
          ...req.body
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(error);
      res.status(404).json({
        error
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together the following ts file to test this:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { Estate } from './entity/Estate';

createConnection().then(async connection => {
    const estate = new Estate();
    estate.estateNum = 0;
    estate.estateId = 'alpha';

    await connection.getRepository(Estate).save(estate);

    estate.estateId = 'beta';

    await connection.getRepository(Estate).save(estate);
});
```

It works as expected (based on the following log output):

```
query: SELECT "Estate"."estate_num" AS "Estate_estate_num", "Estate"."estateId" AS 
"Estate_estateId" FROM "estate" "Estate" WHERE ("Estate"."estate_num" = ?) -- 
PARAMETERS: [0]
query: BEGIN TRANSACTION
query: INSERT INTO "estate"("estate_num", "estateId") VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: 
[0,"alpha"]
query: COMMIT
query: SELECT "Estate"."estate_num" AS "Estate_estate_num", "Estate"."estateId" AS 
"Estate_estateId" FROM "estate" "Estate" WHERE ("Estate"."estate_num" = ?) -- 
PARAMETERS: [0]
query: BEGIN TRANSACTION
query: UPDATE "estate" SET "estateId" = ? WHERE "estate_num" = ? -- PARAMETERS: 
["beta",0]
query: COMMIT
```

I did notice that if you you do not await the save results, typeorm will attempt to insert the row twice (because the first save didn't complete before the second started).

Could this be your problem?

(Note I used sqlite3 in this example).